# Actualizar datos en una base de datos usando PHP

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Me preguntaba si saben alguna forma de modificar una fila de una tabla SQL usando PHP, sin tener que crear un propio procedimiento en SQL.

Comment: Escribiendo la sentencia SQL en PHP y procesándola por PDO por ejemplo

Comment: Me parece que el esta hablando de no tener que usar sql, si es así puedes usar un ORM para php tienes uno llamado Elloquent orm.